# null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint error in Django using Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save "Contact Us" on my page to a PostgreSQL.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.TextField(blank=False)
    contact_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

Here is my view:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname = request.POST['fullname']
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        contact_date = request.POST.get('contact_date')
        user_id = request.POST['user_id']

        contact = Contact(fullname=fullname, message=message, email=email, contact_date=contact_date, user_id=user_id)
        contact.save()
        messages.success(request, 'You have succesfully submitted your message. We will be in touch with you shortly')

        return redirect('index')
```

This is the error I am getting

```
null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, Great job guys!, null, null, null, 9).
```

I typed Great job guys into the drop message field.

This is how the HTML looks like

```
<form class="containerForm" action="{% url 'contact'%}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value={{user.id}}>
                        {% else %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="0">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control"  placeholder="Full Name">
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Drop A Message">

                        <input type="submit" value="Send A Message">
                    </form>
```

Kindly help. I have spent some hours on this.

Comment: try to fix the name in the html tags :)

Comment: you forgot to change the values for name in the html for email and message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same input names for fullname, email, message.

Try this HTML

```
<form class="containerForm" action="{% url 'contact'%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value={{user.id}}>
    {% else %}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="0">
    {% endif %}
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control"  placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Drop A Message">

    <input type="submit" value="Send A Message">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I never noticed it. However, I still have issues with the contact_date. Still giving the violates not-null constraint error. I had to delete the column from the model. Everyother thing works.

Comment: @ojo Try this `contact_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: Thanks @Eugenij. I made the mistake of adding contact date has a variable in my views function. I took it out and everything worked perfectly.